# Gif transition (sample attached)

Tags: animation, gif, adobe-after-effects

How can I make the following transition in After Effects (or another software maybe)? I have the different colours of the piano as pictures, I just don't know how to make this transition! Please check the video attached. Thanks!

https://we.tl/N3pD4yDBHh

Comment: Hello Alex, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. Could you please explain what part of the effect you are having problems with, what you have tried and why it didn't live up to your expectations? That way, we can help you within the space of a few paragraphs, which is this site's scope. If you have any questions, have a look at the [help] or feel free to join us in [chat] once your reputation allows you to (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: It would also help to host the video yourself someplace.  I know that I am certainly not about to download some "video" a random person posts on the internet.  Post it on youtube or vimeo and then share that link with us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a little video, check the link.

An easy web solution is using a svg with fill transition and css, simpler than create a gif.

https://youtu.be/I53vnnXl7yM

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://ezgif.com/maker

Just select the "crossfade frames" option and it will generate the intermediate frames for you automatically. You can change the duration and frame count according to your needs. I threw together a quick example from 2 frames I took from GIF in the other post you made. If you upload the originals in png format, it should have better quality.

[image: example]